Laplace's equation on half disc with a B.C
Solve for the Laplace’s equation on a half disc
\begin{cases}
∆v(r, θ) = 0\\
0 ≤ r ≤ 1, 0 ≤ θ ≤ π \\
v(r, 0) = 0, v(r, π) = π, v(1, θ) = 0
\end{cases}
I used separation of variables i.e,
$v(r,θ) = \phi(θ)G(r)$
Then
$\frac{1}{r}\frac{d}{dr}(r\frac{dG}{dr}) = -\frac{1}{\phi}\frac{d^2\phi}{dθ^2} = \lambda$
While I solving it, using $\lambda>0$, $v(r,θ) = \Sigma A_nr^nsin(nθ)$, but the boundary condition $v(r,\pi) $ make this zero.
What should I do? Or am I on a right path?

Hint. Make the substitution $v(r,\theta)=u(r,\theta)+\theta$.

Oh.... I was close I thought $v(r,\theta) = u(r, \theta)+\pi$... anyway, why should I change $v$ to $u$? can we just use $v(r,\theta) +\theta$ to solve this? And what is $u$ in here?

Working with $u$, you have to solve $\Delta u=0$ with the boundary conditions $u(r,0)=u(r,\pi)=0, u(1,\theta)=-\theta$.
